# TextBlock MultiBinding throws exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, multibinding

A `TextBlock`, should only be visible if a `CheckBox` is checked (`x:Name=DisplaySubscriber`) or the Binding string is not null or empty.

This is my approach:

```
<CheckBox Content="Display Subscriber" x:Name="DisplaySubscriber" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SubscriberString, Mode=OneWay}" >
        <TextBlock.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding>
                <Binding ElementName="DisplaySubscriber" Path="IsChecked" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToVisibleConverter}"/>                        
                <Binding Path="SubscriberString" Mode="OneWay" Converter="{StaticResource StringIsNullEmptyConverter}"/>    
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Visibility>
</TextBlock>
```

But I got this error:

> Provide value on 'System.Windows.Data.MultiBinding' threw an
>   exception.

Comment: Please check if `DisplaySubscriber` checkbox exists or not, and try with `IsThreeState` property of `CheckBox`.

Comment: Check Inner Exception. that should give you information about real problem

Comment: There must be some converter level problem. Plz post converter code.

Comment: InnerExeption: Cannot set MultiBinding because MultiValueConverter must be specified

Comment: yeah you need to create a MultiValueConverter for a MultiBinding instead ov a ValueConverter for each Binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

converter:

```
public class TextBlockVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if((value[0] != null && (bool)value[0]) || (value[1]!=null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(value[1].ToString())))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }    
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

xaml:
define the converter in resource:

```
<local:TextBlockVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextBlockVisibilityConverter"/>
```

use it in the multibinding

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextBlockVisibilityConverter}">
                <Binding ElementName="DisplaySubscriber" Path="IsChecked"/>                        
                <Binding Path="SubscriberString" />    
</MultiBinding>
```

Comment: You have to check, if value[1] is not null and the return values should be Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Collapsed - then it works :)